# How to get the demo of the Internet Archive Bookreader working in 2022?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, build

I am trying to use the Internet Archive Book Reader. I basically want to create a book reader on a website with custom pages for a scanned text. I am trying to follow the instructions for the demo in the README:

https://github.com/internetarchive/bookreader

I am relatively new to this kind of thing, and every time I follow the instructions to just get the demo working, I keep getting a multitude of different problems. Here is what I am doing.

1.) download the repository ("bookreader-master") into my Downloads folder using git clone

2.) use “npm install” to download the dependencies

3.) “npm run build” in project folder (“bookreader-master”)

4.) “npm run serve” and open up "http://localhost:8000/BookReaderDemo/demo-simple.html"

These are more or less the instructions in the GitHub README, but when I open “http://localhost:8000/BookReaderDemo/demo-simple.html”, the page is blank in chrome. When I open it in safari, the book reader loads but the pages are blank. I have tried trying to update dependencies using npm-check, but nothing is working.

I can’t find any easy-to-follow resources on this that are up to date. I think Jquery might be the issue here, but I am not sure how to fix it. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A little late but hope this help other people that get to this question

First I download the project from [openlibrary](https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/bookreader) and in VSC I use the bash terminal to run the commands npm install, npm run build and run serve, then I notice that some samples are "empty" or thats what they look like, If you inspect the page you can see that the `body` and `div's` are `heigh: 0` this is because some css file are not rendering correctly so I just put in the `div` with `id:BookReader` this style: `style="width:100%;height:100vh;overflow:hidden;"` and comment the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="BookReaderDemo.css"/>` and just use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../BookReader/BookReader.css"/>`